# Change color after footer

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a footer at the bottom of my page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    Contact us: newproject@ThundrApps.com, +1 (781)-974-9782
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer {
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}
```

This works fine, however when I try to scroll past the footer, I see white (which is the background of the rest of my page). How would I make the color blue if the user tries to scroll after the footer?

An example of what I'm talking about can be found here: http://support.yikyakapp.com/

Comment: When you say "when I try to scroll past the footer", do you mean when you scroll on a touchscreen device?

Comment: @MichaelP. no I mean when you are on your laptop and are at the bottom of the page and then try to continue to scroll. it bounces back, and you normally see white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a background color to your body tag.

(Example: view the source for this page and change the background color to the body tag to black and try scrolling down, it'll show up as black instead)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```